# Is it safe to store std::future in a member variable and overwrite this member variable repeatedly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to use `std::async` to run the time consuming task of starting and stopping some external equipment in a separate thread so that the GUI stays responsive whilst doing this.

I have learned that when the `std::future` returned from `std::async` goes out of scope it waits on the async task. Since I do not want to wait for this (that would block the GUI thread) I store the future in a member variable.

But what happens when the future is never waited on and the member variable is repeatedly overwritten?

Is the following code safe?

```
class StartStop {
public:
    enum State {STARTING, STARTED, STOPPING, STOPPED};
    StartStop() {
        m_legalStateTransitions[(int)State::STARTING] = (int)State::STARTED;
        m_legalStateTransitions[(int)State::STARTED] = (int)State::STOPPING;
        m_legalStateTransitions[(int)State::STOPPING] = (int)State::STOPPED;
        m_legalStateTransitions[(int)State::STOPPED] = (int)State::STARTING;
    }
    bool startInSeparateThread() {
        if (!changeState(State::STARTING)) {
            return false;
        }
        m_startFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() {
            // do the starting, takes several seconds
            changeState(State::STARTED);
        });
        return true;
    }
    bool stopInSeparateThread() {
        if (!changeState(State::STOPPING)) {
            return false;
        }
        m_stopFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() {
            // do the stopping, takes several seconds
            changeState(State::STOPPED);
        });
        return true; 
    }
private:
    bool changeState(State state) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_stateMutex);
        if (m_legalStateTransitions[(int)m_state] == state) {
            m_state = state;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    std::array<int, 4> m_legalStateTransitions;
    State m_state  = State::STOPPED;
    std::mutex         m_stateMutex;
    std::future<void> m_startFuture;
    std::future<void>  m_stopFuture;
};
```

`startInSeparateThread()` and `stopInSeparateThread()` will be called repeatedly  from the GUI thread when the user presses a start or stop button.

Comment: Have you tried it in practice (with some sort of delay in the tasks)? I'm fairly certain the call to `operator=` will block until the existing task completes.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not work. The move assignment will still wait. Here is a quick test case:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <thread>


int main()
{
  std::future<void> fut = std::async([]() {
    std::cout << "future 1 launched\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::cout << "future 1 ended\n";
  });
  fut = std::async([]() {
    std::cout << "future 2 launched\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    std::cout << "future 2 ended\n";
  });
  std::cout << "second future assigned\n";
  fut.wait();
}
```

The output is

```
future 1 launched
future 2 launched
future 1 ended
second future assigned
future 2 ended
```

This indicates that the second thread is immediately launched but the assignment to the `future` object blocks.

What you want to do instead:

1. Keep a list of futures (or a set, however you want to build it)
2. Let the future notify the GUI thread when it is done
3. Let the GUI thread clean up finished futures, which also gives you a convenient place to deal with exceptions

In general I would advise to use the threading mechanism provided by your GUI framework instead of `std::future`. For example Qt's `QFuture` comes with a [`QFutureWatcher`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfuturewatcher.html) that can handle this directly.

Another wrinkle in your original design: Would you really want to have two `start` threads run in parallel if the state transition is triggered twice? Wouldn't you want to block transitions until the current background operation is done?

Therefore maybe a setup like this works better:

- Keep 3 state variables: current state, desired state, transition in progress
- User actions change the desired state
- If the desired state changes and no transition is in progress, a background action is started to change the state
- When the background action finishes, it changes the current state
- If the desired state has changed while this took place, the GUI thread immediately launches a new background action

Comment: Regarding your second comment; two or more threads may enter `startInSeparateThread()` in parallel. However would not only one thread get past the `changeState(State::STARTING)` test? The `changeState()` method is mutex protected so only one thread may enter at a time. The first thread that enters will succeed in changing the state from Stopped to Starting. The other threads will try to change the state from Starting to Starting, which is not allowed. They will therefore fail the `changeState()` test and `startInSeparateThread()` will return false?

Comment: @Andy correct. On closer look, that prevents it at the cost of ignoring desired state transitions. Begs the question why you store two futures when you can only have one thread running anyway. I guess the real code could have different return values. BTW: The `stopInSeparateThread` misses a return value

Comment: Good point. It seems that I only need one future member variable. When starting the state variable prevent another thread from stopping until changeState(State::STARTED); has returned. At this point the stop thread may start. So the stopping may start before the start thread has finished but the only thing  the start thread will have left doing is returning?

Comment: @Andy sounds right. In effect, it shouldn't block for any significant time